# What could cause an ata4.00 error even without any harddrive when installing Debian 9.9 from a live USB?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, live-usb, gdm, debian

I have a problem *installing* (running)  Debian9.9 on my system.

## First my setup:

```
ADATA M2 256G - The destination drive
WDC Blue 2T - Data disk
Samsung EVO 120G - Windows 10 drive

USB SanDisk 16G FAT32 Debian 9.9 Live (created with LiLi USB creator)
```

## What I tried first

When I boot up the USB stick I got many ata4.00 error spam messages, but could install debian 9.9 on the M2 disk. But when I tried to boot after install it ends up with the ata4.00 error spam.

```
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x40 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x80800 act...
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4: SError: { HostInt 10B8B }
ata4: exception Emask 0x40 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x80800 act...
ata4: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4: SError: { HostInt 10B8B }
ata4: exception Emask 0x40 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x80800 act...
ata4: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4: SError: { HostInt 10B8B }
ata4: exception Emask 0x40 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x80800 act...
ata4: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4: SError: { HostInt 10B8B }
ata4: EH pending after 5 tries, giving up
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x40 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x80800 act...
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4: SError: { HostInt 10B8B }
ata4.00 cmd a0/01:00:00:00:01/00:00:00:00:00/a0...
        Inquiry 12 01 00 00 ff 00res 51/54:03:00...
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR  }
```

Or it gets over it and hangs up at the following point:

```
[ OK ] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes
```

Or it spams:

```
[ OK ] Created slice User Slice of Debian-gdm
       Starting User Manager for UID 117...
[ OK ] Started Session c166 of user Debian-gdm. #(c is counting up)
[ OK ] Started User Manager for UID 117...
       Stopping User Manager for UID 117.
[ OK ] Stopped User Manager for UID 117...
[ OK ] Removed slice User Slice of Debian-gdm.
...
```

Short story: It hung up at different stages on each boot, but not once did it get into the desktop environment (gnome). I thought it might be a hard-drive problem.

## What I did to get the problem source

#### 1. Remove other drives

I have removed all drives (and USB) except the M2, but it still resulted in the same error.

#### 2. Remove all start from USB

My thoughts were that the M2 is broken (wondering why it could install without problems), so I removed it, too, and tried to start from USB only. But I still get the same error on startup. So the only thing it could be is the BIOS settings, but I don't have any idea what exactly could solve this.

Windows 10, by the way, starts up without problems selected from grub2...

If you need any more information please let me know. And yes, I searched for this problem, but found only articles related to broken drives. My issue exists even without any drive....

Here is a photo of the error to illustrate the problem:

[image: Error Photo]